# I am trying to give zooming effect for four div's on mouse hover. But the flickering effect is being seen. How to overcome this?

Tags: jquery, html, css, gsap

I have four rectangular boxes (`myimage`, `myimage1`, `myimage2`, `myimage3`). On top of that I have some content to write upon. I have taken those as `div`s, if I hover on that it is showing flicker effect.

```
<div class="row fourbox">
    <div id="myimage">
        <div class="one">
            <div class="col-sm-4 onefourth"><i class="fa fa-plug" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 twofourth"> Motes <span id="spannum1">32</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="col-sm-6 threefourth">Active Motes <span id="spannum2">15</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 fourth"> Standby Motes <span id="spannum3">17</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myimage1">
        <div class="one">
            <div class="col-sm-4 onefourth"><i class="fa fa-plug" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 twofourth"> Sensors <span id="sensornum1">37</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="col-sm-6 threefourth">Active Sensors <span id="sensornum2">20</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 fourth"> Standby Sensors <span id="sensornum3">17</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myimage2">
        <div class="one">
            <div class="col-sm-4 onefourth"><i class="fa fa-plug" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 twofourth"> Network <span id="networknum1">98%</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="col-sm-6 threefourth">Active Motes <span id="networknum2">30</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 fourth"> Standby Motes <span id="networknum3">2</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myimage3">
        <div class="one">
            <div class="col-sm-4 onefourth"><i class="fa fa-plug" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 twofourth"> Coordinator <span id="coordnum1">5 Tx</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="col-sm-12 threefourth">Coord Mac<span id="coordnum2">0x002334457742</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#myimage, #myimage1, #myimage2, #myimage3 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 56px;
}
#myimage {
    background-color: #da9e37;
}
#myimage1 {
    background-color: #be4932;
}
#myimage2 {
    background-color: #0f5b63;
}
#myimage3 {
    background-color: #af7973;
}
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function zoomOnHover(element, zoom, seconds) {
    var timeline = new TimelineLite({
        paused: true
    });
    timeline.to(element, seconds, {
        scale: zoom,
        ease: Elastic.easeOut
    });
    timeline.to(element, seconds, {
        scale: 1
    });
    element.onmouseover = function() {
        console.log("hover detected on " + element.id);
        timeline.restart();
    };
}
zoomOnHover(document.getElementById('myimage'), 1.15, 1);
zoomOnHover(document.getElementById('myimage1'), 1.15, 1);
zoomOnHover(document.getElementById('myimage2'), 1.15, 1);
zoomOnHover(document.getElementById('myimage3'), 1.15, 1);
```

I am not getting what the problem is. I have used `GreenSock` framework for the hover effect. Could anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: Please add a working fiddle.

Comment: This depends on many variables. The duration of the animations. The type of content you're animating (in this case it seems that are images). If we're talking about images, the complexity of the images (shadows, transparency, size, weight, etc). If there are other animations happening. Try all the following: Compress your images as much as possible. Don't use transparent PNGs. Make your animations shorter. Add `force3D:true` to your GSAP configuration object. Finally try to set up a live reduced sample.